# UTC String to Date and UTC Time Calculations

Tags: ios, objective-c, time, timezone, utc

I have a string, that I know will be reference to an UTC timestamp

```
@"2016-01-20T17:00:00"
```

now when converting it to an actual NSDate it returns this when printed out:

```
NSLog("%@", [TimeHelper stringToDateInUtc:@"2016-01-20T17:00:00"]);
-> 2016-01-20 18:00:00 +0000
```

Same thing with a UTC date:

```
NSLog(@"Time in UTC Now: %@", [TimeHelper getNowUtcAsDate]);
```

I also have this method for getting the current time in UTC and convert the string to UTC:

```
+ (NSDate*) stringToDateInUtc:(NSString*)str
{
  NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
  [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
  return [formatter dateFromString:str];
}

+ (NSString*) getNowUtc
{
  NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
  [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];

  NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];
  return [formatter stringFromDate:now];
}

+ (NSDate*) getNowUtcAsDate
{
  return [TimeAndDate stringToDateInUtc:[TimeAndDate getNowUtc]];
}
```

I am doing a calculation off time difference and since I know that the string that gets sent to these methods are absolutely in "UTC" mode. Therefor I need to compare it to an actual UTC date time.

So, why does the strings I input get converted to the wrong timezone - even though they're set as UTC. And also, UTC time from the method is almost always wrong - lots of reference to other posts here. If I reset my clock -2 hours, the UTC timestamp is also -2 hours, which it shouldn't - reason why I'm using UTC as a reference.

Or is it just the output that's wrong? Instead, maybe use the "timeSinceDate" methods to do the calculations?

Point is that no matter if I put the clock back, UTC time will always be right and the string to calculate time since or until current UTC time is always in UTC.

Comment: Try replacing `[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]` with `[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];`.

Comment: I ran your code and it works okay. I mean the debug shows correctly, see below:  time.2016-01-20 13:17:53.148 SegmentCtr[9870:6278479] Time now is 2016-01-20 17:00:00 +0000
2016-01-20 13:17:53.149 SegmentCtr[9870:6278479] Time in UTC Now: 2016-01-20 21:17:53 +0000

Comment: It does not run OK. If I manually set the time in the phone, the UTC is also wrong. Set my time as +1 Hour and and UTC is also +1. Gettng the offset from TimeZone does not work either.