# Manually Set System Clock Screws Up UTC in Android and IOS

Tags: android, ios, datetime, timezone, offset

A continuation of a previous post:
[UTC String to Date and UTC Time Calculations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34909745/utc-string-to-date-and-utc-time-calculations)

Getting UTC time on a Phone where the time is manually set +5 hours, also changes UTC by 5 hours in both Android and IOS. Why is this?

**IOS:**

```
+ (NSString*) getNowUtc
{
  NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
  // or
  //[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

  [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];

  NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];
  return [formatter stringFromDate:now];
}

+ (NSDate*) stringToDateInUtc:(NSString*)str
{
  NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
  // or
  //[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
  [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
  return [formatter dateFromString:str];
}

+ (NSDate*) getNowUtcAsDate
{
  return [TimeHelper stringToDateInUtc:[TimeHelper getNowUtc]];
}
```

**Android:**

```
public static Date getNowUtc()
{
    return stringToDate(dateToString(new Date()));
}

public static Date stringToDate(String dateString)
{

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm");
    TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");
    format.setTimeZone(timeZone);

    try
    {
        Date date = format.parse(dateString);
        return date;
    }
    catch (ParseException ex) {}

    return null;

}
```

I have looked at **DST** for both Android and IOS. On IOS these values are 0 and on Android they return 3600 if a Date with UTC TimeZone is converted to a Local TimeZone (+1 GMT here... so) but adding +5 hours to the system clock does break all calculations based on time. And on Android, **getRawOffset()** and **getOffset()** - methods...

How can I obtain a 100% certain UTC NSDate/Date when the system clock has been manually changed or automatically otherwise? UTC is not supposed to change. Is the only option to check for a date against some timeserver - which isn't failsafe.

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "where the time is manually set +5 hours"? And what do you mean by "which isn't failsafe" in your last sentence? (Fundamentally, you can't trust the local clock not to have been tampered with, so you *have* to use a network resource of some kind.)

Comment: Note that converting a value to a string and back is almost never the right thing to do. It's not at all clear why you expected that to be useful.

Comment: I would recommend using an online resources

Comment: @Rod_Alongquin I only meant that using an online resource would not maybe not work at a time where no network connection is available - when having the actual UTC time very important.

Comment: @Jon_Skeet Manually override automatic time in either of the phone - appearantly people do that.

Comment: You either trust the device clock (which is in the user's control so it can't be trusted) or you ping an NTP server and get the real time. If the device has no network connection then it is impossible to know if the time you get is correct or not.

Comment: I'm not an ObjectiveC guy by any means, but in the Java example, it's quite likely that the `java.util.Date` object returned is indeed correct, and that you are seeing it adjusted to local time *when you consume it elsewhere*.  (Perhaps the same thing with iOS, not sure)